# jQuery toggle class for element x in container

Tags: jquery, toggle, parent

I have an issue toggling a class for a certain element inside a container. there are multiple elements in different locations. Current HTML:

```
<dl class="sp-methods">
    <h4>Recurring</h4>
    <div>
        <dt class="payment-method>
            <label for="p_method_NORM_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_NORM_" value="NORM" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
    </div>
    <h4>Transfers</h4>
    <div>
        <dt class="payment-method">
            <label for="p_method_FIRL_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_FIRL_" value="FIRL" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
    </div>
 </dl>
```

Be aware: it also occurs that the dt/dd elements are repeated inside the main div, so there is one long list of dt/dd elements, thus not grouped per div:

```
<dl class="sp-methods">
    <h4>Recurring</h4>
    <div>
        <dt class="payment-method>
            <label for="p_method_NORM_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_NORM_" value="NORM" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
        <dt class="payment-method>
            <label for="p_method_NORM_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_NORM_" value="NORM" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
        <dt class="payment-method>
            <label for="p_method_NORM_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_NORM_" value="NORM" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
        <dt class="payment-method>
            <label for="p_method_NORM_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_NORM_" value="NORM" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
    </div>
 </dl>
```

I toggle a class on the change of the radiobutton so the label visually changes. The problem i have is that i can't seem to toggle the correct elements while still relating to `$j(this)` since the dt element sometimes sits inside its own div, and sometimes it sits right in the main div with all the other dt's, thus i can't use .siblings. At least i think.

Please help, thanks :)

```
$j('.sp-methods label input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    $j('.sp-methods .payment-method').removeClass("checked");
    $j(this).parent().parent().addClass("checked").siblings().removeClass("checked");
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. From what I have understood, you are already removing all the the `checked` class from all elements with class `payment-method` and then relatively assigning the `check` class to the closest `dt` tag, I don't get why do you need the `.siblings().removeClass("checked")` part since you have already removed this class in the previous line.

Comment: You are right, this code hasn't been reviewed for a while. But the HTML code changed so i need to change the JS code as well. I will edit my question to show the new HTML code.

Comment: I added the second possibility of HTML. So all the dt's in one div, and not multiple divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following javascript is sufficient to cover both cases, I have used jquery `closest` to reach the `dt` rather than 2 `parent` function calls:

```
$('.sp-methods label input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        // first reach the closes dl and find all the dt and remove the class checked
        $(this).closest('.sp-methods').find('.payment-method').removeClass("checked");
        // then find the closest dt and add the class checked
        $(this).closest('dt').addClass("checked");
    });
```

You have a problem with your markup where you missed a quote for class attribute of some dt elements :

`<dt class="payment-method>` shall be `<dt class="payment-method">`

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$('.sp-methods label input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('.sp-methods').find('.payment-method').removeClass("checked");
        $(this).closest('dt').addClass("checked");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class="sp-methods">
    <h4>Recurring</h4>
    <div>
        <dt class="payment-method">
            <label for="p_method_NORM_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_NORM_" value="NORM" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
    </div>
    <h4>Transfers</h4>
    <div>
        <dt class="payment-method">
            <label for="p_method_FIRL_">
                <input type="radio" id="p_method_FIRL_" value="FIRL" name="payment[method]" title="">
            Overschrijving
            </label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            //content not important
        </dd>
    </div>
 </dl>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But actually my current code interfered with existing code by another dev... So i was really breaking my head on this for such a simple problem. Bleh! Thanks Git Blame  ^^